# Visual Studio - VB - Windows forms project - 'variable' is not declared. It may be inaccessible

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, lync-2010

I'm trying to compile this code for a simple Lync "bot" as found [HERE](https://www.mikesel.info/how-to-build-a-lync-bot/).

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and have the Lync 2010 SDK (and Lync 2010 client) installed.  I know the required DLL from that SDK is imported correctly as I have used it elsewhere in a PowerShell project successfully.

When trying to build the solution, I get the same problem that the first commenter on that site got but didn't get a resolution to.  I have added references to anything under "Extensions" that started with "Microsoft.Lync." (there are 4 of them).  My specific errors:

```
------ Build started: Project: WindowsApplication1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Users\MyUser\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb(31) : error BC30451: '_InitializeFlag' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
C:\Users\MyUser\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb(46) : error BC30451: 'LycConversation' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
C:\Users\MyUser\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb(46) : error BC30451: 'Lyc' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
C:\Users\MyUser\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb(47) : error BC30581: 'AddressOf' expression cannot be converted to 'Object' because 'Object' is not a delegate type.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And my specific code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Lync.Model
Imports Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation
Public Class Form1
    Public WithEvents _Client As LyncClient
    Public WithEvents _ConversationMgr As Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ConversationManager
    Private WithEvents _LocalIMModality As InstantMessageModality
    Public _LycConversation As Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.Conversation

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            _Client = LyncClient.GetClient()
            _ConversationMgr = _Client.ConversationManager
            Select Case _Client.State
                Case ClientState.Uninitialized
                    _Client.BeginInitialize(AddressOf InitializeCallback, Nothing)
                Case ClientState.SignedIn

                Case ClientState.SignedOut
                    _Client.EndSignIn(_Client.BeginSignIn(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing))
            End Select
        Catch ex As AlreadyInitializedException
            MessageBox.Show("Another process has initialized Lync")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeCallback(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
        _Client.EndInitialize(ar)
        _InitializeFlag = True
        _Client.EndSignIn(_Client.BeginSignIn(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing))
    End Sub

    Private Sub _ConversationMgr_ConversationAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ConversationManagerEventArgs) Handles _ConversationMgr.ConversationAdded
        _LocalIMModality = TryCast(e.conversation.Participants(1).Modalities(ModalityTypes.InstantMessage), InstantMessageModality)

    End Sub

    Private Sub _LocalIMModality_InstantMessageReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.MessageSentEventArgs) Handles _LocalIMModality.InstantMessageReceived
        Dim strRec As String
        strRec = e.Text.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "").Replace("'", "''")
    End Sub

    Public Sub SendIM(ByVal strMessage As String)
        Dim modal = DirectCast(LycConversation.Modalities(Lyc.ModalityTypes.InstantMessage), InstantMessageModality)
        modal.BeginSendMessage(strMessage, AddressOf SendMessageCallback, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendMessageCallback(ByVal r As IAsyncResult)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: This error is pretty straight forward. The errors have nothing to do with your dll. You have not declared these variables.

Comment: I don't understand how some people on that site (its author included) have compiled this code correctly then, and me and the one other guy have not.

Comment: Declaring a variable is done like thus - `Dim aVariable As Object` so if you don't declare an object it will be inaccessible as your error states. Please get a beginners book to learn the basics and stop just coping and pasting code you find from the web that you have no idea how to use.

Comment: Are you sure?  For `LycConversation` how would that be declared?  It's being used as a parameter to a function that seems specific to the Lync SDK.

Answer (score 2):

This was an error in the original code.  On [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/487080/How-to-Send-Lync-Instant-Message-in-Plain-Text) I found someone using the `Lyc` variable for a similar purpose.  I copied the `Imports` payload into my function like so:

```
Public Sub SendIM(ByVal strMessage As String)
        Dim modal = DirectCast(_LycConversation.Modalities(Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ModalityTypes.InstantMessage), InstantMessageModality)
        modal.BeginSendMessage(strMessage, AddressOf SendMessageCallback, Nothing)
    End Sub
```

The other part was a typo: `LycConversation` should have been `_LycConversation` per the fourth statement of the Form1 Class:

```
Public _LycConversation As Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.Conversation
```

I am unable to test if the code works the way it is supposed to, but it compiles and executes now.